# Truncating decimal digits numpy array of floats

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to truncate the float values within the numpy array, for .e.g.

```
2.34341232 --> 2.34
```

I read the post [truncate floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python) but its for one float. I don't want to run a loop on the numpy array, it will be quite expensive. Is there any inbuilt method within numpy which can do this easily? I do need output as a float not string.

Comment: Numpy provides the **around** method. The syntax is `np.around(numpy_array, num_decimals)`. For example: `a = np.array([2.3434]), np.around(a, 2) --> produces array([2.34])`. Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: this looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008858/formatting-floats-in-a-numpy-array/21009774#21009774

Comment: Do you actually want to discard the data after the 2nd decimal place, or do you just want to change how the data is displayed? If the former, use the `numpy.around` or `numpy.round` method.

Comment: @AlonAlexander `num = ((num*100)//1)/100` this logic only works for positive values. For  example to truncate negative value to one decimal , `x = -2.134` then `(-2.134*10//1)10`  gives `-3`, which is not an acceptable answer.!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try out this modified version of [numpy.trunc()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trunc.html).

```
import numpy as np
def trunc(values, decs=0):
    return np.trunc(values*10**decs)/(10**decs)
```

Sadly, `numpy.trunc` function doesn't allow decimal truncation. Luckily, multiplying the argument and dividing it's result by a power of ten give the expected results.

```
vec = np.array([-4.79, -0.38, -0.001, 0.011, 0.4444, 2.34341232, 6.999])

trunc(vec, decs=2)
```

which returns:

```
>>> array([-4.79, -0.38, -0.  ,  0.01,  0.44,  2.34,  6.99])
```

Comment: Happy to report this seems to run in only about half the time as `np.around` for anyone switching their rounding -> truncating logic.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html#numpy-round):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4) ** np.pi
a
=> array([  0.        ,   1.        ,   8.82497783,  31.5442807 ])
a.round(decimals=2)
=> array([  0.  ,   1.  ,   8.82,  31.54])
```

Comment: How is this the answer when the question is for *truncation*, not rounding? (I know, I know, the asker accepted it. So I'm really mystified at them, even more so than this answer.)

Comment: Rounding might be subtle when not carefull. Please see my answer for real truncation.

Comment: I think this answer is not correct to the question. Casually, the third decimal is less than 5 in all array elements and for this reason the output is successful, however if you change the decimal numbers ( 'a.round(decimals=3)') to 1 or 3, it outputs 8.825, what is wrong, and if you want to truncate, it should output 8.254