# How to truncate a series/column of a data frame with single operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

There are operations to round or floor or ceiling a column/series of a dataframe but how can one specify the precision for a column and truncate the rest of the values?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (1.21233123, 1.2412304498), 'b':(2.11296876, 2.09870989)})
```

Given this simple data frame, lets say I want to truncate column a and column b to 3 precision without rounding, I simply want to remove the rest of the precision.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (1.212, 1.241), 'b':(2.112, 2.098)})
```

This would be a result df, there should be a column operation that can be executed but it seems that you can only specify precision for rounding.

Comment: What is that besides rounding?

Comment: What about `df.round(3)`?

Comment: It is not rounding, if I rounded the series you can see in Andy Hayden's answer below that you get 2.099 not 2.098. I do not want to round up just limit the precision of the column.

Comment: You can try numpy.trunc() as in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021972/truncating-decimal-digits-numpy-array-of-floats

Comment: Yes truncate has to be used but as seen in @Chris answer, truncate has to be manipulated in order to get the solution of a specific precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html):

```
In [11]: df.round(3)
Out[11]:
       a      b
0  1.212  2.113
1  1.241  2.099
```

To "round down" you can subtract `0.001 / 2` from the DataFrame first:

```
In [12]: (df - 0.0005).round(3)
Out[12]:
       a      b
0  1.212  2.112
1  1.241  2.098
```

Comment: Referencing the example output I had, round does not work, I do not want to round up I simply want to truncate the value at a specified precision for the whole series.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how that is equivalent because the resulting data frame is completely different? The resulting df has a value of 1.599 at b1

Comment: yes sure that works but that should not be the solution to truncating,  it doesn't seem to be reproducible on different values of a series. For example if there was any number that would change the value before the decimal when 0.0005 was subtracted, the round would be wrong.

Comment: " it doesn't seem to be reproducible on different values of a series." please provide an example.

Comment: My mistake, that does cover any case I can think of at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: @rye_bread I agree that it feels like this ought to be easier, e.g. a flag for `round`.

Comment: I was looking for someone to just tell me that there was some sort of round function with a parameter but sadly as far as I have found that is not the case. Appreciate the hack though!

Answer (score 3):

Use `numpy.trunc` with a bit of trick:

```
import numpy as np

n_precision = 3
df = np.trunc(df * (10 ** n_precision))/ (10 ** n_precision)
print(df)

       a      b
0  1.212  2.112
1  1.241  2.098
```

Since `np.trunc` discards the fractional part, you first multiply numbers by the order of your precision, do `np.trunc`, divide them back to get the desired output.

Comment: Interesting, this is a similar approach to @AndyHayden in that there is not a direct function to do this, it has to be contrived from other existing functions even within the trunc function of NumPy. Thanks for the tip!