# Generate a random float numpy array of x size and n decimals

Tags: python, numpy

I need to get a random numpy array and each value must be with 2 decimals. I have tried something like this:

```
wH2 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2)
wH2 = np.around(wH2,2)
```

But around is modifying the values from the array.

ex: After around 0.7485443 will be 0.75.
I need to keep it 0.74

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncating decimal digits numpy array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021972/truncating-decimal-digits-numpy-array-of-floats)

Comment: @PaulVio Why do you need a certain number of decimals?

Comment: I have homework to create a neural network for solving XOR, and my teacher asked me to check if the number of decimals matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a random array, does it really matter the precision of rounding?

In any case, try this:

```
wH2 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2)
wH2 = wH2*100//1/100
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you:

```
wH2 = np.fix(np.random.uniform(0, 10000, 2))/100
```