# Formatting a 2D Numpy Array Float -> Percentage

Tags: python, numpy, string-formatting

I have a 2D numpy array like

`x = np.array([[3,3],[3,1]])`

```
Out[107]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [3, 1]])
```

I would like to format it to print percentages of the total:

```
array([['33.3%', '33.3%'],
       ['33.3%', '10.0%']]
```

I've tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008858/formatting-floats-in-a-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891790/how-to-pretty-printing-a-numpy-array-without-scientific-notation-and-with-given) but have yet to get these to work:

```
pct_formatter = lambda x: "{:.2%}".format(x/x.sum() * 100 )
pct_formatter(x)

TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

another attempt:

```
with np.set_printoptions(formatter=pct_formatter):
    print(pct_formatter(x))

AttributeError: __exit__
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#user a dataframe to format the numbers and then convert back to a numpy array.
pd.DataFrame(x/float(np.sum(x))).applymap(lambda x: '{:.2%}'.format(x)).values
Out[367]: 
array([['30.00%', '30.00%'],
       ['30.00%', '10.00%']], dtype=object)
```