# np.round, or np.around doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array:

```
arr = np.array([66.5, 89.4000015, 57.2000008, 86.9000015, 64.5999985,
      92.3000031, 74.1999969, 76.0999985, 92.0999985, 81.6999969,
      72.0999985, 78.8000031, 81.4000015, 95.4000015, 73.5      ,
      58.5999985, 68.3000031, 68.9000015, 68.6999969, 92.       ])
```

I tried to round each number, and used `np.around`:

```
[in]  np.around(arr, 2)

[out] array([66.5, 89.4, 57.2, 86.9, 64.6, 92.3, 74.2, 76.1, 92.1, 81.7, 72.1,
   78.8, 81.4, 95.4, 73.5, 58.6, 68.3, 68.9, 68.7, 92. ])

[in]  np.around(arr, 4)

[out] array([66.5, 89.4, 57.2, 86.9, 64.6, 92.3, 74.2, 76.1, 92.1, 81.7, 72.1,
   78.8, 81.4, 95.4, 73.5, 58.6, 68.3, 68.9, 68.7, 92. ])

[in] np.around(arr, 5)
[out] array([66.5, 89.4, 57.2, 86.9, 64.6, 92.3, 74.2, 76.1, 92.1, 81.7, 72.1,
   78.8, 81.4, 95.4, 73.5, 58.6, 68.3, 68.9, 68.7, 92. ])

[in]  np.around(arr, 6)

[out] array([66.5     , 89.400002, 57.200001, 86.900002, 64.599998, 92.300003,
   74.199997, 76.099998, 92.099998, 81.699997, 72.099998, 78.800003,
   81.400002, 95.400002, 73.5     , 58.599998, 68.300003, 68.900002,
   68.699997, 92.      ])
```

When the number of decimals is less than `5`, the `np.around()` does not work. When it is larger than `6`, the `np.around` is working well.

Any help is appreciated.

Anne

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It seems to work quite well.

Comment: Can you say what results you expect? Those results look fine to me.

Comment: I believe you might be confusing [`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) with [`numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html).

Comment: Or that NumPy rounds to the nearest even value.

Comment: I am expecting that array[66.5000, 89.4000, 57.2000, ....] when I used np.around(arr, 4). But it gave me array[66.5, 89.4, 57.2, ....]

Comment: @anne what "that"?

Comment: As @MarkDickinson said, you need to provide your expected results and point out how they differ.

Comment: @anne `66.5000` and `66.5` are the same number. Their string representation is different. You can use float formatting to achieve that result. But do you only want to display them or are you trying to write to a file? (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008858/formatting-floats-in-a-numpy-array for a couple of options).

Comment: I am expecting that the results from np.around(arr,4) should be different from that of np.around(arr,2). That is to say, the result of np.around(arr,2) should be array[66.50, 89.40, 57.20, ....], while that of np.around(arr,4) should be array[66.5000, 89.4000, 57.2000,.... ]  Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is not rounding, adding zeros to floats does nothing unless you are treating these numbers as strings. For that you have the [`.nf` notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995615/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-to-always-show-2-decimal-places), where `n` is the number of figures you want to show.

Comment: @user2285236, Luca Thanks a lot for the explanation. I understood now.  Maybe I need to format them to achieve what I want. Thank all.

Answer (score 5):

## How to: round

Based on the *"unexpected behaviour"* you are describing, I believe you haven't clear which round operations or the effect they have on numbers or how to format floats as strings.

Let's explore the differences when rounding to `n=4` digits different values.

### Baseline

We define an array with 13 values (13 just to get some digits), from 0 to 1.

```
values = np.linspace(0, 1, 13)
```

The array contains:

```
array([0.        , 0.08333333, 0.16666667, 0.25      , 0.33333333,
       0.41666667, 0.5       , 0.58333333, 0.66666667, 0.75      ,
       0.83333333, 0.91666667, 1.        ])
```

### [`numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)

[`numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)
 will increase the value of the *n*-th figure when the *n+1*-th is greater or equal to `5`, do nothing otherwise. It is the same as [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html).

```
np.round(values, n)
>>> array([0.    , 0.0833, 0.1667, 0.25  , 0.3333, 0.4167, 0.5   , 0.5833,
   0.6667, 0.75  , 0.8333, 0.9167, 1.    ])
```

### [`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html)

[`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) will increase the value of the integer part when there exists digits and drop the digits.

```
np.ceil(r)
>>> array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

### [`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html)

[`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) will just drop the digits.

```
np.floor(r)
>>> array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

### [Number string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

There are a multitude of ways to format numbers as strings: we will explore some of the more commonly used.

#### Formatting as floats

To format floats you use the symbol `.nf`, where `n` is the number of digits you want to leave. It will drop all the following figures and add zeros as padding when required to do so.

```
[ "{:0.4f}".format(v) for v in r]
>>> ['0.0000', '0.0833', '0.1667', '0.2500', '0.3333', '0.4167', '0.5000',
     '0.5833', '0.6667', '0.7500', '0.8333', '0.9167', '1.0000']
```

#### Formatting as percentages

To format floats as percentages you use the symbol `.n%`, where `n` is the number of digits you want to leave, considering that the number will be multiplied by `100`. It will drop all the following figures and add zeros as padding when required to do so.

```
[ "{:0.4%}".format(v) for v in r]
>>> ['0.0000%', '8.3333%', '16.6667%', '25.0000%', '33.3333%', '41.6667%',
'50.0000%', '58.3333%', '66.6667%', '75.0000%', '83.3333%', '91.6667%',
'100.0000%']
```

#### Formatting in scientific notation

To format floats as percentages you use the symbol `.ne`, where `n` is the number of digits you want to leave, considering that the number will be converted to [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). It will drop all the following figures and add zeros as padding when required to do so, adding at the end the exponent of the number in scientific notation.

```
[ "{:e}".format(v) for v in r]
>>> [
    '0.0000e+00', '8.3333e-02', '1.6667e-01', '2.5000e-01', '3.3333e-01',
    '4.1667e-01', '5.0000e-01', '5.8333e-01', '6.6667e-01', '7.5000e-01',
    '8.3333e-01', '9.1667e-01', '1.0000e+00'
]
```

#### Bonus: formatting complex numbers

Suppose you have a complex number `a = 3j+2`: to print its components you would proceed by accessing its attributes:

```
"The real component is {0.real} and the imaginary one is {0.imag}".format(a)
>>> 'The real component is 2.0 and the imaginary one is 3.0'
```